# How get Y combinator through S combinator or others?

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinators, s-combinator

I have the equation Y = FY (fixed point equation). How to get of it the equation for F through other combinator (in particular S- combinator with first fixed parameter)?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What would "the equation for `F`" mean, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this -- consider the functions *g* and *g ∘ g*. Then *Y(g)* and *Y(g ∘ g)* are both *g(g(g(g(g(...)))))*, so there's no way to go from *Y(F)* to *F* in general.